# Firefox and Eclipse don't recognize the proxy on RHEL

Tags: firefox, proxy, eclipse

I have a proxy configuration in .bashrc

```
http_proxy=http://my-company-proxy.com:80
https_proxy=https://my-company-proxy.com:80
export http_proxy
export https_proxy
```

If I try to access the external world via curl, it works.

If I try to configure this proxy as a proxy in Eclipse or Firefox, the connection times out.

What could be the issue with specific application not working with a valid proxy?

Comment: it's probably that the applications don't look for http_proxy etc. They have their own different mechanism to set a proxy.

Comment: They do look. For example, I configured Firefox to "manual proxy configuration" to the same proxy server, and get the same result. 
Also, if I change the proxy string to some invalid settign, eclipse throws an error to logs. That means it loads the proxy from the settings...

Comment: This was clear in the question, I didn't read correcly. Anyway it's possible the dual nature of this proxy (http + https on same port) doesn't help.

Comment: You could try doing captures (tcpdump...) at least for the http case and see the dialog with the proxy